# Python 3 list comprehension sum and concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
mylist =[[16, 'August', 2014, 540, 10], [16, 'Iunie', 2014, 100, 20], [23,'August', 2014, 540,10], [23,'Septembrie', 2016, 540,30], [21,'August', 2014, 422, 30]]
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
manipulate = [[16, 'August 2014, Iunie 2014', 540, 30], [23, 'August 2014, Septembrie 2016', 540, 40], [21, 'August', 2014, 422, 30]]
```

And to explain it, in mylist (list of lists) I want to check each list for the index 0 (first element) when it founds the same value element (in my example 16 ===16) and do the fallowing operation: keep only the first list and accumulate to it index 1 + index 2 (like this example -> 'August', 2014 and 'Iunie', 2014 to 'August 2014, Iunie 2014') and sum the index 4 (like in my example 20 + 10).

I manage to do this:

```
manipulate=[i for i in mylist if i[0] not in [mylist[idx][0] for idx in range(0,mylist.index(i))]]
```

but this will output:

```
[[16, 'August', 2014, 540, 10], [23, 'August', 2014, 540, 10], [21, 'August', 2014, 422, 30]]
```

What I have to add in order to also do my desired computations?, I work with python 3. Thank you so much!

Comment: does it have to be a list-comprehension?

Comment: Not necessarily!

Comment: can it be more than two lists that match? also which item with index 3 do you keep?

Comment: Yes, there can be more than 2 list, and I keep only the first one (index 3).

Comment: I would urge you to reconsider your desired output since this is significantly ugly, not consistent and not very practical to work with as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite verbose but I feel like it had to be, to be *understandable\readable*:

```
mylist = [[16, 'August', 2014, 540, 10], [16, 'Iunie', 2014, 100, 20], [23, 'August', 2014, 540, 10], [23, 'Septembrie', 2016, 540, 30], [21, 'August', 2014, 422, 30]]

g = {}
for x, *y in mylist:
    g.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

def formater(obj, a_list):
    if len(a_list) == 1:
        return [obj] + a_list[0]
    else:
        conc = ', '.join('{} {}'.format(sub[0], sub[1]) for sub in a_list)
        return [obj, conc, a_list[0][2], sum(sub[3] for sub in a_list)]

manipulate = [formater(k, v) for k, v in g.items()]
print(manipulate)  # [[16, 'August 2014, Iunie 2014', 540, 30], [21, 'August', 2014, 422, 30], [23, 'August 2014, Septembrie 2016', 540, 40]]
```

Comment: Thank you also, I will have many more elements that will have the same index 0.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, this works, I will accept this for answer since was the fastest valid one. Thanks again sir :), I will test this more at home.

Comment: Can you please, Ev. Kounis exaplain what are you doing here :  a_list[0][2]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the list is already sorted by the first elements, you can use `itertools.groupby` to group the elements and then assemble the new sublists.

```
manipulate = []
for group in (list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=lambda x: x[0])):
    lst = [group[0][0]] + [x for g in group for x in g[1:3]] + [group[0][3]] + [sum(g[-1] for g in group)]
    manipulate.append(lst)
```

You could even put those in a single horrible list comprehension if you want...

```
manipulate = [[group[0][0]] + [x for g in group for x in g[1:3]] + [group[0][3]] + [sum(g[-1] for g in group)]
              for group in (list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=lambda x: x[0]))]
```

The result is this (I do not merge the strings, as I'm not sure you really meant this):

```
[[16, 'August', 2014, 'Iunie', 2014, 540, 30], 
 [23, 'August', 2014, 'Septembrie', 2016, 540, 40], 
 [21, 'August', 2014, 422, 30]]
```

If you want to merge the dates, use this slightly more horrible list comprehension:

```
manipulate = [[group[0][0]] + [', '.join(' '.join(map(str, g[1:3])) for g in group)] + [group[0][3]] + [sum(g[-1] for g in group)]
              for group in (list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(mylist, key=lambda x: x[0]))]
```

This way, the result is:

```
[[16, 'August 2014, Iunie 2014', 540, 30], 
 [23, 'August 2014, Septembrie 2016', 540, 40], 
 [21, 'August 2014', 422, 30]]
```

This works with an arbitrary number of elements per group. If the sublists are not sorted by first element, either sort them first, or use a dictionary to do the grouping.

Comment: this does not exactly match the desired output. The string concatenation bit is left outside.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Agreed, I was not sure if that was intentional or just an artefact of manually forging the output. E.g. in the last segment, it's still `[21, 'August', 2014, 422, 30]` and not `[21, 'August 2014', 422, 30]`

Comment: This last segment I disagree with as well but since that is what OP wants..

Comment: I will test this also, Thanks tobias so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
mylist =[[16, 'August', 2014, 540, 10], [16, 'Iunie', 2014, 100, 20], [23,'August', 2014, 540,10], [23,'Septembrie', 2016, 540,30], [21,'August', 2014, 422, 30]]

new_list = [[mylist[i][0]]+[mylist[i][1]+" "+str(mylist[i][2])]+mylist[i][3:] for i in range(len(mylist))]

final_lists = [[c+", "+d if isinstance(c, str) and isinstance(d, str)  else c+d if c != d else c for c, d in zip(new_list[i], new_list[i+1])] for i in range(0, len(new_list)-1, 2)]+mylist[-1]
```

Comment: Looks good, thank you so much, it only miss the comma at 'August 2014 Iunie 2014'.

Comment: I added a new list : [16, 'Octombrie', 2014, 540, 100] and now the output looks like this : [[16, 'August 2014, Octombrie 2014', 540, 110], [39, 'Iunie 2014, August 2014', 640, 30], [44, 'Septembrie 2016, August 2014', 962, 30], 21, 'August', 2014, 422, 30] instead of [[16, 'August 2014, Iunie 2014,  Octombrie 2014', 540, 130], [39, 'Iunie 2014, August 2014', 640, 30], [44, 'Septembrie 2016, August 2014', 962, 30], 21, 'August', 2014, 422, 30]